# Проектирование базы данных в mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных

Существует база данных, в которой есть таблицы: `department`, `employee`, `calendar`, `event`.

Немного расшифровки: существует рабочий, который работает в департаменте. У рабочего есть календарь на год (месяц и дни), каждый день в каждом месяце отмечается какое-либо событие (выходной, рабочий день, отпуск и тд). Это  производственный календарь.

Нужно было спроектировать базу данных. Не совсем уверен, что правильно сделал, прошу помощи или хотя бы направления на правильный путь.

И еще вопрос: календарь в базе данных (месяцы и дни месяца) нужно заполнять вручную или можно как-то сделать это проще?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А что происходит в конце года, 31 декабря, календарь полностью стирается и начинается новый ? Если нет, то как отличить записи прошлого года от текущего. Отсюда следует, что дату надо хранить не отдельными полями (тем более не ясно в каком виде вы собрались хранить день, если отводите под него 45 символов). Сделайте одно поле типа `date` и храните с годом. На счет событий не ясно, может быть несколько событий в один день ? (так у вас сейчас в БД заложено). Хранить календарь отдельно от событий вообще не вижу смысла, было бы гораздо проще хранить событие и поле даты у него.

Comment: И вообще все зависит от того, как дальше используется этот календарь, какие "события" вообще могут быть и может ли быть в один день более одного события. Может статься, что будет выгоднее хранить вообще в виде интервалов дат, одной записью "с 18 по 22 мая рабочие дни", "16-17 выходные".

Comment: дан календарь на ОДИН год. в одном дне будет храниться одно событие. мне год не нужен, нужны только месяцы и дни.

Comment: Поверьте, год нужен, всегда. Вот записали вы расписание в БД и теперь у вас запрос, который должен выдать на экран собственно сам календарь. Скорее всего в календаре потребуется выводить день недели, а как его в запросе получить если год не известен ? И даже если заказчик клянется, что год только текущий, то первый же его запрос будет перед новым годом, ввести расписание на следующий, не трогая текущий

Answer (score 0, accepted):

К таблицам `department`, `employee` вопросов нет. Хранить в `calendar` отдельно месяц и день это двойной источник проблем (15 месяц, 45 день), лучше хранить дату, если нет возможности, то год и день.

По заданию выходит, что у вас счетное количество событий, значит для них должна быть отдельная таблица без привязки к чему либо

```
event
-----
idevent
event
```

Сам производственный календарь преобразуется

```
calendar
--------
idcalendar
caldate
idemploye
idevent
```

Уникальный ключ по вашей задаче для этой таблицы должен быть `caldate+idemploye`.

По поводу заполнения таблицы `calendar` - стандарта нет. Можно заполнить для сотрудника на месяц событием по умолчанию.

Обычно календарь без привязки к сотруднику в БД хранят отдельно, чтобы указывать продолжительность каждого рабочего дня. Смысла ссылаться на такой календарь особо нет, т.к. всегда можно сделать связь по дате.

Comment: в целом понятно, а заполнить даты в таблице calendar нужно вручную или можно проще сделать?

Comment: Я в ответе написал, что можно заполнить, например, значением `рабочий день` для всех сотрудников на месяц вперед, а потом по ходу некоторым изменять. Или вопрос в другом?

Comment: @skipperoker Конечно "в ручную". Создавать записи для дней в которых нет "события" не надо. А раз есть событие, значит его кто то где то в программе для данного сотрудника ввел, и вот в момент ввода собственно и создается запись. P.S. Кстати, для такой таблицы суррогатный ключ idcalendar я бы скорее всего не делал бы, а первичным ключом сделал бы (idemploye, caldate)

Comment: @Mike а чем плохо/хорошо иметь отдельное поле для первичного ключа?

Comment: @AlexR. Суррогатный ключ полезен, если предполагаются ссылки на данную запись из других таблиц. Для обеспечение уникальности вам все равно надо делать уникальный ключ на день сотрудника. Кроме того, конкретно в MySQL (в innoDB, в котором скорее всего таблица и будет) таблица физически лежит на диске блоками в порядке первичного ключа и поиск по первичному в 2 раза быстрее, чем по любому другому. Так как задача в подавляющем кол-ве случаев предполагает получение расписания конкретного сотрудника на интервале дат, то его получение из смежных областей диска оптимально

Comment: @AlexR. Хотя если основные запросы будут вида "дай расписание всех сотрудников на 15 мая", то тогда дату в ключе надо ставить на первое место.

Comment: @Mike спасибо за пояснение

Comment: @Mike позвольте резюмирую: department и employee оставляю также как и сделал (один ко многим), таблицу event делаю с полями idevent (первичный ключ), event (собственно само событие). Таблицу calendar делаю с полями caldate (где будет дата), idemployee (связь с таблицей employee), idevent (связь с таблицей event). Поправьте, если не так, заранее благодарен

Comment: @skipperoker Да, так, и `primary key(caldate,  idemployee)` (или наоборот, в зависимости от последующего использования)

Comment: @Mike появился вопрос. Если я делаю primary key - caldate - получается дата уникальная для таблицы calendar. То есть на одной дате не может быть двух employee, получается. Если в департаменте 10 человек, то, к примеру, дата 2019-01-01 будет одна для одного человека. Как быть в таком случае?

Comment: @skipperoker primary key надо сделать из двух полей сразу

Comment: @Mike то есть между таблицами calendar и employee нужна третья таблица caldate_idemployee , так?

Comment: @skipperoker Нет, первичный ключ не обязательно должен состоять из одного поля. Он может быть из нескольких полей сразу. я же не просто так писал `primary key(caldate, idemployee)` вот прямо в таком виде в SQL на создание таблицы он и указывается

Comment: @Mike сапсибо огромное, туплю что-то. Теперь до конца все прояснилось.

Comment: @Mike И снова прошу прощения, столкнулся с еще одной штукой: у моих employee может быть одна и та же дата. То есть caldate 10.01.2020, idemployee 1, idevent 1 и следующая запись 10.01.2020, idemployee 2, idevent 1. Вывожу эту таблицу из двух строк в браузер с помощью Thymeleaf, отображается две строки caldate 10.01.2020, idemployee 1, idevent 1 , то есть вторую строку затирает. Не могу догнать, почему происходит затирание...

Comment: @skipperoker "отображается две строки" и "вторую строку затирает" по моему  противоположны по смыслу. Если клиентское вредство не способно правильно отобразить БД то это проблема этого клиентского средства и проблему надо искать там. Но конечно БД всегда проектируется с учетом всей специфики будущего приложения. никто кроме вас не может сказать как на самом деле она должна выглядеть